# Reorder cert in cert store within shell

Tags: bash, shell, openssl, ssl-certificate, sh

I have the following cert chain :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**I want to reorder the 3 certs within it by dropping the third cert and swapping the first two.**

so this would become :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

whats the best way to do reorder the above in shell?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Inian - nothing, not really good at sh.

Comment: This question kind of smells of "give me the code". The cited duplicate should get you started. It uses `awk` to parse individual certificates from a concatenation of PEM encoded certificates. You need to figure out how to store them in a shell variable, and how to print them in the order you want or need.